# dataTables Sort order Desc issue

Tags: jquery, mysql, sorting, datatable, datatables

I know there are similar questions like this and used solutions but it didn't solve my problem.

*I get data from SQL order by `asc`:*

```
$sql = "SELECT * From stats ORDER by id Asc";
```

*now i want to show data on tables order by `Desc`* on DataTable:

**JS:**

```
$('#Table').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "order": [
        [0, "desc"]
    ]
});
```

but look like DataTable can't control sorting here, neither `asc` or `desc`.

i tried many solutions like:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [{
        "asSorting": ["desc", "asc"]
    }, ]
});
```

but nothing changed. i made the example on [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L59x40w3/) but it working good here, when you change `asc` to `desc` it will change. i think duo i get data from sql with `asc` dataTable can't handle sorting, but i need get data from SQL by `ASC` then sort it on dataTable by `DESC`, any solution?

Comment: Are you loading the data using AJAX loader on data table ?

Comment: load data with `php` to `html` table @AbhikChakraborty

Answer (score 0):

Please refer

```
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/
```

which has 
1) Type based sorting 
2) Custom data source sorting